# How to open xml file from command line?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xml file which has xslt applied to it. I am using 3 files in xslt. I need to pass three file names as arguments to this xsl file from command line. 
I can open the xml page with xsl applied to it by clicking any of three xml files.

My xsl file is-

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:variable name="file1" select="document('File1.xml')"/>
<xsl:variable name="file2" select="document('File2.xml')"/>
<xsl:variable name="para"  select="document('para.xml')"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Parameter</th>
      <th>File1</th>
      <th>File2</th>
      </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="document('para.xml')/catalog/cd/title"/></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="document('File1.xml')/catalog/cd/title"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="document('File2.xml')/catalog/cd/title"/></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="document('para.xml')/catalog/cd/artist"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="document('File1.xml')/catalog/cd/artist"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="document('File2.xml')/catalog/cd/artist"/></td>
    </tr>

  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My File1.xml is-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="first.xsl"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

Comment: depending operating system command may change, on which os you are working ?

Comment: Windows operating system

Comment: "*I need to pass three file names as arguments to this xsl file from command line.*" That won't do any good, because your XSLT file does not have any parameters that would accept those names. I am not sure what exactly your question is about.

Comment: The command line interface to an XSLT processor varies from one XSLT processor to another. You need to explain which one you are using.